# Does Wikipedia allow URL fetching via Google App Engine?

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, url, web-applications

I am writing a Python web app and in it I plan to leverage Wikipedia. When trying out some URL Fetching code I was able to fetch both Google and Facebook (via Google App Engine services), but when I attempted to fetch wikipedia.org, I received an exception. Can anyone confirm that Wikipedia does not accept these types of page requests? How can Wikipedia distinguish between me and a user?

Code snippet (it's Python!):

```
    import os
import urllib2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = "http://wikipedia.org"
        try:
          result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
          result = 'ahh the sky is falling'
        template_values= {
            'test':result,
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Comment: What Exception is being thrown? I assume it a subclass the urllib2.URLError, and it might give you better insight into the problem.

Comment: Can't you use the urlfetch api? It seems to work for me. AFAIK urllib2 default user-agent is banned from wikipedia and you can't change it on gae.

Comment: "An exception" is pretty unhelpful. Show us the stacktrace!

Comment: @systempuntoout You can change the user agent, you just can't remove the App ID from it.

Comment: @systempuntoout Yes you can. I just tested it with shell.appspot.com, and as expected it adds `AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: shell)` to the end of whatever user-agent header you specify.

Comment: @Nick show your code or it did not happen :)

Comment: What makes you think this wouldn't be the case? `req = urllib2.Request("http://myapp.appspot.com/", headers={"User-Agent": "Foo"}); urllib2.urlopen(req)`

Comment: @Nick uhm, there's something wrong in the urllib2 wrapper in my opinion. Passing the headers to the Request constructor works well, but the snippets above both fail.

Comment: Great answers! Sorry I didn't provide a stacktrace -- I will keep that in mind next time (novice programmer here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urllib2` default user-agent is banned from wikipedia and it results in a 403 HTTP response.
You should modify your application user-agent with something like this:

```
#Option 1
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'MyUserAgent')]
res= opener.open('http://whatsmyuseragent.com/')
page = res.read()

#Option 2
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://whatsmyuseragent.com/')
req.add_header('User-agent', 'MyUserAgent')
urllib2.urlopen(req)

#Option 3
req = urllib2.Request("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/", 
                       headers={"User-agent": "MyUserAgent"})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Bonus link:
High level [Wikipedia Python Clients](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code#Python)
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python

Comment: Those snippets fail on shell.appspot.com because of a bug in shell, not because of a bug in urllib: If you create an object on shell in one command, then try and modify it in another, the changes aren't persisted. Put your code above in a function and execute that and it'll work fine.

Comment: Really great answer! I am really impressed and the explanation + link helped a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your user-agent to any string you wish; it will be modified by App Engine to append the string `AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: yourapp)`. In urllib2, you can set the user-agent header like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/", headers={"User-Agent": "Foo"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```