# Variables response from file_get_contents for 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Upcoming_singles'

Tags: php, caching, screen-scraping, wikipedia

```
file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Upcoming_singles');
```

returns a different response (2 products) from visiting the same address using the Chrome web browser (shows 4 products).

Upon inspection, I suspect this might be related to

> Saved in parser cache key with ... timestamp ...

in the html returned. The timestamp is older when I use `file_get_contents()`

Any ideas on how to fetch the latest info using `file_get_contents()`?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `file_get_contents`?

Comment: yes, i meant file_get_contents(), thank u!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `file_get_contents` is making an http request, it would be good to check the user agent specified.

I've heard of problems fetching data with some user agents. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543571/does-wikipedia-allow-url-fetching-via-google-app-engine).

You can specify other options (including the user agent) by using stream context:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

Take a look at the file_get_contents [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Also, as Jack said, cURL is a better option.

**EDIT:**

You get me wrong. What you've to add is a different user agent. For example, using the user agent from mozilla firefox get you the 4 results:

```
<?php

    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; es-AR; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.23"
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Upcoming_singles', false, $context);
    print $file;
```

But, i think it's not "legal", it's not good to cheat on that. I think there must be any other user agent that wikipedia provides to fetch its data from outside apps.

Comment: user option is set. and context is set like this,   $opts = array('http' =>
   array(
    'header'  => 'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
   )
  );

It still gives me the same problem. I will try cURL tommorow and let you know, too.
Thank you!

Comment: I tried setting the user agent to "Mozilla/5.0", and yeah I get 4 results as if I was using a browser. Resetting it to the old user agent, "scraper", now also returns 4 results. It fixed my problem, but I wonder why. THank you so much.

Comment: It must be becouse of som sort of caching. Wikipedia could cache static files for certain types of agents giving preference to browsers. Anyway, i recommend you to ask them, or read about it.

Comment: I suspect the User-Agent header is a red herring -- the only effect it should have on the results is that some user agents are banned from Wikipedia and will receive a HTTP 403 Forbidden response. Since you did get a normal response, it's probably not that (but see the responses by me and Krinkle anyway). My guess would be that this was just a random case of temporary cache staleness.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) it is required that all requests identify themselves. I would strongly recommend against *faking* a browser user-agent. There is no need for that.

Millions of machines access Wikipedia and other Wikimedia Foundation projects all the time. Just identify yourself, your script, it's not hard!

```
// Identify your bot, script, or company.
// E.g. Link to a website, or provide an e-mail address.
ini_set( 'user_agent', 'MyBot/1.0; John Doe (contact: info@example.og)' );

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$contents = file_get_contents( 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox' );
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using cURL and setting a header to get the latest info, not caches (Sorry I can't remember the exact header to set)

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you really should be using the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) instead of trying to screen-scrape the information from the human-readable category page.  For example, [try this query](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3aUpcoming_singles) using [`list=categorymembers`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers).

Some notes:

- Choose the appropriate [results format](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aData_formats) (which, for PHP, is probably `format=php`).
- The default limit is 10 results per query, but you can increase it up to 500 with `cmlimit=max`.  After that, you'll need to use the [query continuation mechanism](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries).

You can also use one of the existing [MediaWiki API client libraries](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code) to take care of these and other little details for you.

And finally, please play nice with the Wikimedia servers: don't send multiple simultaneous queries, and cache the results locally if you're going to need them again any time soon.  It's a good idea to include your contact information (a URL or an e-mail address) in the User-Agent header, so that Wikimedia's sysadmins can easily contact you if your code is causing excessive server load.